# UITextView not showing scroll bars

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I have made UITextView programmatically but it is not showing the vertical and horizontal scroll bars. The code I have used is as follows,

```
UITextView *txtView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(origin, imgFrame.size.height + 10, mScrollView.frame.size.width, 300)];
txtView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12];
txtView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
txtView.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
txtView.editable = NO;
txtView.scrollEnabled = YES;
txtView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[txtView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth]; 
//[txtView flashScrollIndicators];
[txtView setText:[mDescArr objectAtIndex:index]];
[mScrollView  addSubview:txtView];
[txtView release];
```

How can I make the scrollbars show?

Answer (score 4):

I think there is no regular way to make them always visible (On Purpose!).

The BOOL **`txtView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=TRUE`**/showsHorizontalScrollIndicator only shows the bar if the scrollView is active and hides it after some milliseconds inactivity.

If you comment `[txtView flashScrollIndicators];` out then it only shows it once, to show the User that there is a possibility to scroll.

I think one (ugly) way to make it possible is, to call flashScrollIndicators more often, but this is no proper solution.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have any text in it? It will only show the scroll bars if the text is bigger than the size of the view.

Answer (score 0):

As bizarre as it may sound, do you ever collect and remove/edit subviews of your UITextView? When calling subviews from a UITextView (or UIScrollView), it will also return its scroll bars.